# Treating order of elements in arrays as order of input?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it good practice to use the order of elements in arrays as signifying an implicit order?

The question sounds kinda funny. I'm asking is this ok:

```
{
    raceWinners: ['john', 'peter', 'paul']
}
```

John was first place, Peter was second, and Paul got third place. It's implied by the order.

Or would this be better practice:

```
{
    raceWinners: [{
        name: 'peter',
        placement: 2
    }, {
        name: 'john',
        placement: 1
    }, {
        name: 'paul',
        placement: 3
    }]
}
```

I see the value of the second example because everything is explicit to you.

While in the first example, you can really muck up things if you accidentally popped(), when you should have shifted().

Comment: That completely depends on your intended way of using those arrays.

Comment: Neither is better without any context to be used in.  The second one needs more memory though.

Comment: Depends on your usage. How important the order is to you. If it is used in a single place to do some manipulation, then it is ok to have array (implied by order). Or else if you have some other things as well to do based on placement. Then go for second option.

Comment: How come upvotes for an opinion based question?...

Comment: First one is better if you think that: if the second person is disqualified (i.e. removed from the array) the person in third place should automatically be in 2nd place. With the second option you'd have to do a "cascade update" to update the placement property of each object, which seems messy. However, if you intend to pass that object around, explicit properties might be a good idea to avoid "implicit" relevance of the array order.

Comment: @TedNyberg Hey, I didn't even realize that! Nice!

Comment: With the second you could have multiple people on the same placement, and also have holes.

Comment: @Bergi Yea, the second example is nice because it's explicit but now you need extra logic to a)find the placement b)slice c)then put in the correct one. Whereas in the first code example, it's more streamlined to reason about the order of things.

Comment: @TedNyberg Edit: I know what you mean, my bad! Earlier: "What do you mean by 'pass the object around'?"

Comment: If, for example, you'd have a "getRaceResult()" function that would return the array and be invoked by other scripts, it might make sense to have an explicit "position" property to indicate who's in 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc, just to make the response object more explicit and thus reduce risk of misunderstandings.

Comment: @wle: Seems like you already know the answer :-) Yes, it depends a lot on what you want to access in what manner. Btw, I'd also throw in `{peter:2, john:1, paul:3}` or `[{placement:1, name:"john", id:0x32}, {placement:2, …}, …]`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I really enjoyed talking about this! It seems like the answer is: a) Implicit if you're not planning on manipulating the data very often for the memory perks, and b) Explicit if you have any doubt whatsoever that it's gonna be an important data set that will be manipulated often.